# Visual Studio GitHub is linked to a stranger account

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I created a new private repository in Visual Studio 2022 (device A) and I commit and pushed every version. Ok so far. When I pulled the project from another PC (device B) I saw that everything I pushed from my device A is displayed from another account!

I have never seen it before, does that mean I got hacked or something? I have no idea I am new to Github and Git.

All commits from my project:

[image: commits from my project]

**g7501** is my account but the other one is linked to my VS device **A** somehow!

Can someone tell me if this is okay?

My branches: [image: branches]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every Git commit has two names attached to it, an "author" and a "committer".  These two names each consist of two parts: a given name and an email address.  For instance, `A U Thor <thor@example.com>` has a given name of `A U Thor` and an email address `thor@example.com`.

Git stores these two entities into the commit metadata at the time you (or whoever) make the commit.  From then on, these *can never be changed*.  Not even Git itself can change them.  But when Git creates a *new* commit, it totally believes whatever *you* say your `user.name` (given name) and `user.email` (email address) settings are, so you can run:

```
git -c user.name="Fred Flintstone" -c user.email=fred@bedrock.prehistory commit
```

for instance to make your *next* commit be by `Fred Flintstone <fred@bedrock.prehistory>`.  (Git will use this as both author and committer.)

If you use *Git* to examine the commits, you'll see the author line by default in `git log` output.  Use `git log --pretty=fuller` to see both author and committer.  They will generally be the same, since `git commit` makes them the same; they will differ only if you, for instance, take an emailed patch (via, e.g., `git format-patch`) from some *other* author and use `git am` to turn that patch into a commit.  Then the other author will be the author, but you—your `user.name` and `user.email`—will be the committer.  (There are similar cases that don't involve email, but do involve two different people collaborating, that produce the same effect.)

Again, these *cannot be changed* after the commit is made.  They present as, e.g.:

```
commit acd34fd5f60ab01e871dfa3a3bb8b81828ac181d
Author:     Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason <avarab gmail.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Apr 8 18:00:25 2022 +0200
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Fri Apr 8 11:21:11 2022 -0700
```

(though I've replaced the `@` with space to cut down on spam to these guys) when *Git* shows them to you.

**Other programs that are not Git** "like" to obscure Git's actual stored information and show you *something else* instead.  For instance, GitHub can show you something else entirely.  This has nothing to do with Git!  This is done *by* GitHub, in a way *GitHub* control.  For more about how GitHub do this, see [their community blog](https://github.community/t/why-is-my-commit-associated-with-the-wrong-person/10199).

(I do not use Visual Studio and do not know what it does.)

Comment: Problem solved. All  what I had to do is change my user.name & .email. Thank you so much to make me understand this.